# If $x=1\mod3$ and $x=0\mod2$, what is it $\mod6$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If you know what a number mod two different primes is (3 and 2) in this case, how can you tell what the mod is of the two products?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/693441/18398